# "Converse" of second Fundamental Theorem of Calculus?

Tags: calculus

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous. Let $F: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be such that $F(b) - F(a) = \int_{a}^{b} f(x) \, dx$ for all $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$. Is $F$ differentiable, and is $F’ = f$?

One reason I am asking is in the context of probability. Given the cumulative distribution function $F$ of a continuous random variable $Y$, $F(y) := P(Y \leq y)$, can the probability density function $f := F'$ be (alternatively) characterized by the property $F(b) - F(a) = \int_{a}^{b} f(x) \, dx$ for all $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Are you familiar with the first fundamental theorem of calculus?

Comment: The answer to your question is yes, and that is called the first fundamental theorem of calculus. That said, you should be careful when you are using this in probability theory: the probability density function does not always exist.

Comment: @Jackozee Thanks. I didn't realize it was a formulation of the first fundamental theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Fix any $a \in \mathbb{R}$. Define $G: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ by $G(x) = F(x) - F(a) = \int_a^x f(t) \, dt$. Differentiating and applying the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, we get $G'(x) = F'(x) = f(x)$, so $F' = f$.